# ViaXMR payouts time length

Tags: mining-pools, mining, mining-theory

I've been mining on ViaXMR.com for nearly a month now and still no payout, is this because its a small pool or something else? Hobbyist miner using one GPU/CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViaXMR pool hasn't found a block since Dec 3: https://www.viaxmr.com/#/blocks  So no one has been paid out in a while.  It's been a really unlucky streak.

Also, the minimum payment is 0.4 XMR. Look at the Pool Config here: https://www.viaxmr.com/#/home

So you will have to mine long enough to accrue 0.4XMR before the pool will pay you at all.

You won't see any XMR for a long time in that pool.

MoneroOcean (or some other http://moneropools.com/) may be a better pool for you: 0.03 XMR minimum payouts: https://moneroocean.stream/#/dashboard

Comment: I caught the tail-end of that Dec 3rd payout with 0.0029088659 XMR. I wondered if anyone else had used ViaXMR and what their experience was. I get about 150H/s on the i7 CPU and around 425H/s on the GTX970